# Write $\cos(4 \theta)$ as a polynomial in $\sin \theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find constants $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $e$ such that $\cos(4\theta)=a(\sin(\theta))^4 + b(\sin(\theta))^3 + c(\sin(\theta))^2 +d\sin(\theta))+e$ for all angles $\theta$. In other words, write $\cos(4\theta)$ as a polynomial in $\sin \theta$. How am I supposed to solve this problem?

Comment: $40$ should probably be $4\theta$

Comment: Indeed! If not, a solution is $a=b=c=d=0$, $e=\cos(40)$ ;-)

Comment: Joking aside, please look at [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) and [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to **show some work**.